# techniques for bulk data processing

Tags: php, message, bulk

I'm looking for a technique to do the following and I need your advices.
I have a huge (really )table with registration ids and I need to send messages to these ID owners. I cant send the message to many recipients at once, this needs to be proceeded one by one. So I would like to have a script(php)  which can run in many parallel instances (processes) by getting some amount from db and processing it. In other words every process needs to work with a particular range of data. I would like also to stop each process and to be able to continue message sending from the stopped user to another set of users who didnt get the message yet. 
If it's possible? Any tips and advices are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to set a cron job, typically one of the best approaches to run large batch operations with PHP scripts:

http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/running-php-cron-jobs-regular-scheduled-tasks-in-php-172/

Your cron job will need to point to a PHP script which does the following:

1. Selects a subset of recipients from your large DB table, based on a 
   flag set at #3 (below), identifying the next batch to process
2. Send email to those selected recipients
3. Saves a note of current job position success/fail (i.e. you could set a
   flag next to each recipient in the DB who is succesfully mailed, these are then not selected when the job is rerun)

Answer (score 0):

Parallel processing is possible only to the extent of the configuration of your server. Many servers can serve pages in a parallel fashion, but then again, it is limited to a few. Instead, the rule of thumb is to be as fast as possible and jump to the next request.

Regarding your processing of a really large list of data in your database. You will first of all need a list of id for the mailing your are doing:

```
INSERT INTO `mymailinglisttable` (mailing_id, recipient_id, senton) SELECT 123 AS mailing_id, mycontacttable.recipient_id, NULL FROM mycontacttable WHERE [insert your criterias for your contacts]
```

Next you will need to use either innodb or some clever logic for your parallel processing:

With InnoDB, you can do some row level locking, but don't ask me how, search it yourself, i don't use InnoDB at all, but i know it is possible. So you read the docs on that, select and lock some rows, send the emails, mark as sent and wash rinse repeat the operation by calling back your own script. (Either with AJAX or with a php socket)

Without InnoDB, you can simply add 2 fields to your database, one is a processid, the other is a lockedon field. When you want to lock some addresses for your processing, do:

```
$mypid = getmypid().rand(1111,9999);
$now = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
mysql_query('UPDATE mymailinglisttable SET mypid = '.$mypid.', lockedon = "'.$now.'" LIMIT 3');
```

This will lock 3 rows for your pid and on the current time, select the rows that were locked using:

```
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM mymailinglisttable WHERE mypid = '.$mypid.' AND lockedon = "'.$now.'")
```

You will retrieve the 3 rows that you locked correctly for processing. I tend to use this version more than the innodb version cause i was raised with this method but not because it is more performant, actually, i'm sure InnoDB's version is much better just never tried it.

Comment: at this point we can loose some recipients when I'll stop the message sending in the middle of the process. :( but maybe I cant eliminate this type of situation. either I'll lose some recipients or will send some of them twice.

Comment: Nope, with my version, not the innodb one, the locks can be reset on all rows which are not SENTON. You set your "SENTON" date only when the mail is gone. The lock is to prevent selecting the row twice...

Comment: sorry, misunderstood you:) so u meant I have to update senton every time the message is sent ? if yes, hm.. that means periodical updates that are not very good.

Comment: Well, remember that what we say on this board is only suggestions, you should take the one that suits you the most and adapt it if necessary. It's part of the process of becoming a great programmer... :)

Comment: agreed:) now I wonder about php processing part. i.e. if somehow I'll get first 1000 rows, than I should get the next set of 1000 users whom I havent sent messages yet. should I add timeouts or something else. actually I dont like the idea of timeouts , but dont know what else can I do.

Comment: Well, you need to implement a timeout strategy here. For example, if a message was locked but not sent within 10 minutes of it's reservation, you should unlock it for more batch processing. Reduce the time based on how much time a batch takes to process. Remember, smaller batches are better than larger ones. Mostly if you work with small units of fast code. Tend to get away from bulky code if you want to work with units of data...

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with using PEAR modules, I'd recommend having a look at the pear Mail_Queue module.

http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Queue

Well documented and with a nice tutorial. I've used a modified version of this before to send out thousands of emails to customers and it hasn't given me a problem yet:

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-queue.mail-queue.tutorial.php

Comment: thanks Tom, but actually these messages are not regular emails , but android push notifications. Therefore I need to process message sending my own.

Comment: Then this might work: You can select out of your list like this:

`$threads = 10  // How many threads are you running`
`$thread_id = 1 // Which of your PHP threads is this`
`$sql = 'SELECT * FROM list WHERE sent=0 AND id % ' . $threads . ' = ' . $thread_id;`